# Configuring subdomains on tomcat8

Tags: apache, tomcat, subdomain, tomcat8

I have tomcat8 running on windows. I need to create a subdomain for my app. I used the steps below to configure the subdomain in server.xml but I'm getting a 404 on hitting the subdomain url.

1. I have added 127.0.0.0 mapping for ab123.com and subdomain.ab123.com to my hosts files.
2. update server.xml (below)
3. copied dirs from "C:\tomcatapps\testapps" to "C:\tomcatapps\testapps\subdomain" then started tomcat
4. hit ab123.com (works!)
5. hit subdomain.ab123.com (404 error)

**Server.xml**

```
  <Host name="subdomain.ab123.com"  appBase="testapps\subdomain" unpackWARs="true" >
   <Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="C:\tomcatapps\testapps\subdomain" path=""/>
  </Host>
  <Host name="ab123.com"  appBase="testapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

**Tomcat dir structure**

```
tomcatapps
   **testapps**
      host-manager
      META-INF
      ROOT
      **subdomain**
         host-manager
         META-INF
         ROOT
```